# Can't create assets folder in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an assets folder in android studio but the option is grayed out!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbLO4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have set your **minSdkVersion** to less than `16` in `build.gradle (:app)` go and search **minSdkVersion** and set it to minimum `16` I suggest set `21`

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create assets folder res right click and select asset folder i am create easy to create asset folder